# How to compare sql server query performance

Tags: sql-server, performance-testing

I have two ways to get the result from sql server

first way

```
select * from my_view where key='key'
```

second way

```
select * from my_function('key')
```

the two ways do the same thing.
actually the size of the database is low so the execution time is too low ,and i can't tell witch one take less time, but I m not sure that they still be the same if the data base come to grow

So my question is: Is there any way or free tool to compare the exact execution time of the two queries?

Comment: On way could be you fill the table with enogh data too see some velocity. Normaly EXPLAIN is the command that you use e.g. for seeing performance issues.

Comment: right click in your query window. Choose Query Options. Go To "Advanced". Check on SET STATISTICS TIME on and SET STATISTICS IO on. you will see actual execution time and how much IO was performed in the messages tab.

Comment: @Jeremy this way i can compare witch one goes faster, that's what i need thks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

key='key' will be always faster or the same. Never use function on column name (if applicable, use function on the value in the condition eg.: key=function('key')). If you do, SQL Server is not able to use any optimizations on the query (eg. indexes will be ignored).

To ensure query will keep its performance level as your table grows, you will have to set an index on the column.

You can deduce performance from Execution Plan in SQL Server Management Studio (when you execute the query with Include Actual Execution Plan enabled - Ctrl+M). You can also enable Include Statistics (Ctr+Alt+S) to see some performance info.

Answer (score 2):

If you run multiple queries in a batch (one query window) and enable "Include Actual Execution Plan", it'll give each query a "relative cost to the batch".

So if you had two in your batch, if one is < 50% then it's faster than the other.